# Why calling agetty directly from bash doesn't seem to have any effect?

Tags: linux, systemd, login, getty

I try to call `/usr/bin/agetty -` from bash in a terminal-emulator(both X-based and Kernel-based), then it asked me to input a username, but after input that username, it just "freeze" a little while, then dropped me back into my original bash promote.

I started to wonder, agetty is started by `systemd` as a service using the ttyx device and `execve(/usr/bin/login)` so it will give me login promote, because login is configured with `pam_systemd`, so a systemd session will be created. But that's not the result I get when I directly run `agetty -` as I mentioned above, no new session is created when I check `systemctl status`.

Then I thought if it was because agetty run as normal user, it might check its own EUID or something, but that just cause my bash to exit after I input the username.

Ok, I checked `systemctl status` again, it told me systemd run this program as `/sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty2 linux`, ok, I login as root on tty2, then run `agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear - linux`, I got exactly the same situation as in the first place —— I was dropped back to bash again.

I need to understand these experiment results.

I'm using ArchLinux, `/usr/bin/login` and `/usr/bin/agetty` are both from the `util-linux 2.33-2` package.

Comment: A `getty` process opens the named port, prompts for a login name, calls `login`.  If you have another process already using that port (eg your existing shell) then you may get conflicts with the terminal handling.   Typically you would specify an _unused_ port to start a new session on that port.    What is it you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently "recursive `login`" used to do something useful, but it has not been expected to work on Linux for a while now.

I recommending sticking with the more commonly used techniques, such non-recursive `login`, or `su` and `sudo`, because these are better understood, documented, etc for current systems.

Where possible, avoid `su` in favour of `su -l`, as this gives you a clean set of environment variables.

I do *not* know why you see the specific result you describe.  But if you do need to understand the behaviour of "recursive `login`", I can think of two specific points that you need to understand, about what can go wrong with it.

> BUGS
>
> The undocumented BSD -r option is not supported.  This may be  required
>          by some rlogind(8) programs.
>
> A  recursive  login,  as  used  to be possible in the good old days, no
>          longer works; for most purposes su(1)  is  a  satisfactory  substitute.
>          Indeed,  for  security  reasons,  login does a vhangup() system call to
>          remove any possible listening processes on the tty.  This is  to  avoid
>          password sniffing.  If one uses the command login, then the surrounding
>          shell gets killed by vhangup() because it's no longer the true owner of
>          the  tty.
>
> -- `man login`

And if you're using systemd, it tracks login sessions, but it does not allow them to be nested.  This is a [deliberate choice](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7451#issuecomment-346787237) about how systemd login sessions should interact with "`audit` sessions".  `su` / `sudo` do not escape the current "`audit` session".

Currently, I can also see systemd noisily logging about this design every time I run `sudo`.  Do not ask me why this is considered desirable...

```
sudo[1079]: pam_systemd(sudo:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
```

---

Full disclosure: the quote from `man login` continues:

> If one uses the command login, then the surrounding shell gets killed by vhangup() because it's no longer the true owner of the tty.  This can be avoided by using `exec login` in a top-level shell
>          or xterm.

Comment: ArchLinux doesn't get this, maybe you have `pam_systemd` configured for `sudo` in `/etc/pam.d`.